# Error al usar control RequiredFieldValidator al abrir vs 15

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

El proyecto lo inicie en `Visual Studio 13` luego actualizaron a **versión 15**
pero al momento de hacer pruebas da este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando comento las validaciones vuelve a funcionar

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rfvTnitp" runat="server"
                 ControlToValidate="TBUnitp"
                 ErrorMessage="requerido"
                 Display="Dynamic"
                 ValidationGroup="vgProduct" 
                 ForeColor="Red"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: mira [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705149/579895)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ya carga la pagina pero algunos textbox usan autopostback y se muestra el mensaje unos segundos antes de que vuelva a refrescar la pagina